# 17.10 Boot under gdm3 take minutes

Tags: boot, 17.10

I recently upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10. Everything seems to be working OK so far and the bootup under Lightdm is as fast as ever but the bootup under gdm3 takes literally takes minutes.

If I boot under gdm3 and run:

> ```
> systemd-analyze blame
> ```
>
> I get:
>
> ```
> 2min 58.111s rc-local.service
>       7.829s apt-daily-upgrade.service
>       5.612s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
>       4.956s plymouth-quit-wait.service
>       1.830s fwupd.service
>       1.807s monitorix.service
>       1.785s postfix@-.service
>       1.393s dev-sda1.device
>       1.041s speech-dispatcher.service
>        994ms accounts-daemon.service
>        903ms upower.service
>        841ms udisks2.service
>        818ms gpu-manager.service
>        816ms grub-common.service........
> ```

How can I find out why rc-local.service is taking three minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what it was, it was fstrim included in etc/rc.local. I commented it out and the boot under gdm3 is now just a few seconds. I haven't figured out why this worked in 17.04 and in 17.10 under lightdm though.